# why is post method not used?

Tags: html, post, asp-classic, get

**GET** - Requests data from a specified resource

**POST** - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

Why, in the following html file, which means to send message to server (using the post method) there is no message to get from the server. In my opinion, only the post method can be used in the following html.why the coder use get method ?

**[please see w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "html_form_action.asp".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't try to learn anything from w3schools. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: where is the best learning material in the way of learning myself?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature check the resource in my answer

Comment: Can't be bothered a lot of these answers all miss the point, imo you shouldn't use `GET` for anything other than retrieving a hypermedia resource and `POST` for creating / updating (although this is controversial) a hypermedia resource.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misunderstanding on **GET** and **POST**

### **GET**

When using GET as method your form will submit the data as URL-Parameters like:

```
html_form_action.asp?FirstName=Mickey&LastName=Mouse
```

This makes the sent data visible to the normal user in the url box of the browser.

---

### **POST**

When using POST as method, your form will also submit the data but it will hide it from the URL and send as hidden data not visible to the normal user, your URL will then simply be

```
html_form_action.asp
```

However in your asp page you can still access the POST data

POST is mostly used for sensible data like sending password when logging in

**EDIT**: Also check the following resource, it will explain a lot: http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET_(HTTP)_vs_POST_(HTTP)

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but neither do I upvote, since a) this does not directly address the question and b) although the explanation as such is correct, it does not describe the *key* difference.

Comment: which is in your opinion?. IMO this is the key difference

Answer (score 1):

Your description of GET vs. POST is not correct. Both methods *may* send data to the server and *may* get response data from the server. In most situations, some data *is* sent to the server and some response is got. Typically, but not necessarily, the response to GET request is the result of some query (like entries matching the input data), and the response to POST request is a statement of success or failure of some operation (like adding data to a database, or making a purchase).

Generally, GET should be used only for requests that have no side effect (no effect on the state of affairs outside the operation of sending and getting the request) or, more generally, if the request is idempotent, i.e. the side-effects of more than one identical requests is the same as for a single request. For other requests, POST should be used. But this is not a law, just a recommendation. And there are technical reasons for using POST even for pure information queries; see my page [Methods GET and POST in HTML forms - what's the difference?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

Thus, there is nothing strange with a form that has two text input fields and uses method GET. We would normally expect it to be for information retrieval—for getting information, from some data repository, that matches the specific input used. But this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question?! GET and POST are 2 different methods how to submit data to the server. If you chose GET it will end up being URL-encoded in the targetbar with the action script, if you chose POST it will send a POST request to the action script. Either way you will get something back from the action script.

Comment: umm why the downvote? just wanted to point out that there is NO simple solution for not understanding the basics of HTTP requests....